# GitLab CI/CD: Do not destroy a docker container after building

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

My use case is the following: I want to deploy a PHP app to docker after a branch is updated and then leave it running for manual testing.

So I would like to access it under a certain URL.

What I did so far is to create a gitlab docker runner

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner register --url "https://git.example.com/ci" --registration-token xxxx \
     --description "dockertest"  \
     --executor docker \
     --docker-image "php:7.0-apache" \
     --docker-services mariadb:latest
```

And I have a `.gitlabci.yml`

```
stages:
  - deploy

job-deploy-docker:
  only: 
  - docker-ci-test
  stage: deploy
  environment: docker
  tags:
  - docker
  image: php:7.0-apache
  services:
  - mariadb
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get --assume-yes install mysql-client
    - mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mariadb -e "create database ci"
```

The deploy runs `Job succeeded` and then the container is destroyed.

1. How can I avoid destroying the container. Of course it should be cleaned up or reused if a new push is done to a branch.
2. How can I make the web app accessible under a certain external URL (branchname.ci.example.com)
3. Is that even the right approach or should I do it differently?

Comment: Gitlab's documentation does mention such a case: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/review_apps/index.html It's however lacking proper examples.

Comment: @JakubKania Interesting enough ... question is if docker can be used for this and how. They mention I have to setup my own infrastructure for hosting - I was hoping to be able to (ab)use the gitlab runner's docker setup methods

Comment: Of course docker can be used, for example Kubernetes.

Comment: Yes but that means I have to setup a kubernetes infrastructure and add dockerfiles to my projects,right?

Comment: I think this becomes very useful if the ci fails. You can create a local runner, enter the container and inspect the problem. I have seen cases multiple times when scripts work fine on the mac but fail on linux.